# a variable as all values from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, variable-definitions

I have a small Problem with lists and variables.
I want mathematica to calculate a formula I derived for 200 values of w between 0 and 5 in ascending order. (maybe I can define w along the lines of)

```
`npoints=200
 w=n/200*5
 {n,0,npoints}`
```

Now for every value of w I want mathematica to put the calculated value in a list, so I can make a ListPointPlot. How do I do that?
To simplify let's assume the formula is

```
Sin[w]
```

So I want mathematica to calculate the value of the expression for 200 values between 0 and 5 and put the results in a List that I can plot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `npoints = 200;
ListPlot[Table[Sin[w], {w, Subdivide[0, 5, npoints]}]]` ?

Comment: The function you're looking for is `Table` ([link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)).

Comment: Yes that works thank you. Do you also know if there is any way i can re label the axes to show me the value for w instead of the points?

Comment: @HenrieKüppers `ListPlot[Table[{w, Sin[w]}, {w, Subdivide[0, 5, npoints]}]]`

Comment: Great, Thank you guys!

Comment: With @cvgmt comment, you could use the option `DataRange -> {0, 5}`